# How to streaming upload with python requests module (include file and data)?

Tags: python, http, file-upload, python-requests

I have this code [python requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) code snippet(part) to upload a file and some data to the server:

```
files = [("FileData", (upload_me_name, open(upload_me, "rb"), "application/octet-stream"))]
r = s.post(url, proxies = proxies, headers = headers, files = files, data = data)
```

Since this will read the whole file into memory, which may cause some issues in some situations. From the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads), I know it supports streaming uploads like this:

```
with open('massive-body') as f:
    requests.post('http://some.url/streamed', data=f)
```

However I don't know how to change my original code to support streaming. Anyone can help please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently requests doesn't support doing streaming uploads that contain any more data than a single file. The fact that you're sending `data` on your `POST` means you're doing a multipart file upload, and currently Requests doesn't provide you with any way to stream that.

Comment: There is a package that is in the quite early stages of development here: https://github.com/sigmavirus24/requests-toolbelt

Comment: Lukasa thanks for your answer. Do you know if there is a plan to implement this feature?

Comment: Thanks sigmavirus24, I'll take a look.

Comment: May be `pycurl` will be a good idea for such cases.

http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html